# Ripple effect on all clickable items is slow

Tags: android, performance, debugging

I do not know what could it be, but does not look like a performance issue (like doing too much work on the background) because there is no message on LogCat saying Slow measurement, Frames skipped or ConstraintLayout issues. The app animations work perfectly. But, unfortunately, all the clickable elements that I added on the xml:

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

are too slow. That slow, that whenever I click, instead of the smooth animation that moves and starts on the exact pixel I click on, it appears an awful shadow and remains like so for a while (~2 sec).

If it is indeed an android performance issue, how to debug it? Also, I do not know where to start and which information I need to add in order to add valuable information to this question but, if needed, please, ask for it and I will try to add as much information as possible.

The only thing I could say in advance is I am using MVVM and coroutines, so there is no performance issues on that matter, but maybe only UI related?

**EDIT:**

Samsung J2 Prime and Samsung Galaxy Note 3 work good, all animations are good (even though is a small and old device)
Motorola Zoom and Redmi Note 8 Pro are working with laggy animations (animations are meant only the clickable animation (Ripple effect), the ConstraintLayout animations are working smooth.

Comment: Does that happen in all layouts and multiple devices ?

Comment: Yes! Unfortunately to the newer devices and ironically are faster those devices... Multiple layouts too. Almost all of them...